# jQuery if something is more than value then hide and add a button to show whats hidden?

Tags: jquery, hide, show

Exactly what my title says is the problem Im having right now.

Im checking a div for how many links php printed and if there is more than 10 Id like to hide them and add a button that says read more and then it show the rest of the links.

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

     var newsRss = $('#rssNews >li').length;
     var driftRss = $('#rssDrift >li').length;

        $(window).load(function() {
            if(newsRss > 10)
     alert(newsRss);

});

    });
```

this is how far I got with the code.

Ill be happy to hear every tip and trick you guys can help me with!

Best Regards,

Charlie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#rssNews >li').slice(10).addClass("hidemore").hide();
if ($(".hidemore").length > 0) {
  //add your button to the dom here, 
  //and in its click event put:
  // $(".hidemore").show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something fairly straightforward like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("#rssNews, #rssDrift").each(function() {
        if($(this).children(":gt(4)").hide().length)
            $(this).append("<li class='showAll'>Show All</li>");
    });
    $(".showAll").live('click', function() {
        $(this).siblings().slideDown();
        $(this).remove();
    });
});​
```

This hides any children over index 4, meaning it only shows 5 at once.  If it hid any, it adds a "Show All" link...clicking this shows the hidden ones and removes the "Show All" link itself.

You can test how this works here: http://jsfiddle.net/hxrde/

Comment: Thank you guys so much! I didnt think about doin it that way :-D It works exactly the way I hoped it should :D

Answer (score 1):

Charlie,

Simply add the ":gt(4)" to the hideAll function for the siblings:

```
 $(".hideAll").live('click', function() {
    $(this).siblings(":gt(4)").slideUp();
    $(this).parent(0).append("<a class='showAll'>Show all</a>");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

And thanks for the code. Works great!